# Redactor - Superscript button

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

Is there a possibility to ad a 'superscript' button to redactor?

Edit: I found an explanation here: [How can I use <small> <sub> <sub> within a redactor/rich-text field?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/how-can-i-use-small-sub-sub-within-a-redactor-rich-text-field/2695#2695)

But I can't get it to work.

I copy this snippet form: http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/buttons-sup-and-sub/ to  `craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/plugins/subsup.js`

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.scriptbuttons = function()
{
    return {
        init: function()
        {
            var sup = this.button.add('superscript', 'Superscript');
            var sub = this.button.add('subscript', 'Subscript');

            // make your added buttons as Font Awesome's icon
            this.button.setAwesome('superscript', 'fa-superscript');
            this.button.setAwesome('subscript', 'fa-subscript');

            this.button.addCallback(sup, this.scriptbuttons.formatSup);
            this.button.addCallback(sub, this.scriptbuttons.formatSub);
        },
        formatSup: function()
        {
            this.inline.format('sup');
        },
        formatSub: function()
        {
            this.inline.format('sub');
        }
    };
};
```

Then I call the plugin in a custom.json file like this:

```
{
    buttons: ['link','bold', 'italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','image','html'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen', 'subsup'],
    toolbarFixedBox: true
}
```

But that results in nothing. What do I miss?

Comment: Nobody knows this? :(

Comment: Is this now a thing? now that Redactor has been updated as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This complexity is no longer necessary in Craft 3. You can simply add `"sup"` to your `buttons` array in your redactor config.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem so created a plugin to add some of these extras to Redactor.

### Redactor Extras for Craft

https://github.com/elliotlewis/Redactor-Extras
Available plugin are:

- Superscript and Subscript
- Word count
- Alignment
- Custom plugin

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I assume would be to use the formattingAdd (see documentation https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd)

You can find that json file inside config/redactor/*.json.

In my example i am using

```
"formattingAdd": {
      "superscript": {
          "title": "Superscript",
          "api": "module.inline.format",
          "args": {
              "tag": "sup"
          }
      }
   }
```

You can use that to do several things such adding styling to elements and that would become available on the "Format" button dropdown.

```
"formattingAdd": {
      "superscript": {
          "title": "Superscript",
          "api": "module.inline.format",
          "args": {
              "tag": "sup"
          }
      },
    "blue-text": {
      "title": "Blue text",
      "api": "module.inline.format",
      "args": {
        "tag": "span",
        "class": "blue-text"
      }
    },
    "orange-text": {
      "title": "Orange text",
      "api": "module.inline.format",
      "args": {
        "tag": "span",
        "class": "orange-text"
      }
    },
      "white-text": {
          "title": "White text",
          "api": "module.inline.format",
          "args": {
              "tag": "span",
              "class": "white-text"
          }
      }
  }
```

Really powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and ended up creating my own fieldtype that extended a RichText field.

I think there is an oversight in Craft, where additional Redactor plugins aren't loaded even if they are specified in the config.json. But perhaps I'm missing something too?

A simple solution would be to hardcode the loading of the plugin in **craft/app/fieldtypes/RichTextFieldType.php**.

Within the function **_includeFieldResources()**:

add the line:

```
craft()->templates->includeJsResource('lib/redactor/plugins/subsup.js');
```

after the default plugins specified.

Obviously modifying a core file is not recommended, but this should enable a temporary fix. I have built a plugin which autoloads js/css depending on what is specified in the config, but this isn't currently ready for general release. Let me know if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but I can't comment yet.

Craft is out-of-sync with the current version of the Redactor docs. Redactor is on version 10, while the latest Craft build is still on version 9.2.6.

There were a number of breaking changes and additions to version 10 of Redactor, but for some reason Redactor does not maintain a docs archive. So for the moment, we don't have a reliable source for Redactor docs.

See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4899/1027) for more from Craft on this.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I guess I'll wait then. I don't want to alter core files.

Comment: Okay, so now redactor is on v10 within craft 2.3 Ist there a possible solution now without corefile editing?

Answer (score 1):

I made another pretty easy solution:

```
{{ entry.redactor | nl2br | replace({'/m3': '/m<sup>3</sup>'}) | raw }}
```

It just replaces the units with the coresponding html markup. It works nice :) But you need to know which units are used.