# Upgrade Redactor?

Tags: redactor

How soon is the Craft team planning to upgrade to the latest version of Redactor? Redactor version 10.0 introduced some breaking changes and new formatting options, which are not backwards compatible.

The [Craft docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields) link to Redactor V10 docs, which don't apply to Craft's version (9.2.6),  and I can't find any archived copies of Redactor's docs, so... while not quite a showstopper, it's a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We update all of Craft's dependencies on each point release, so Craft 2.3 will have the latest version of Redactor in it.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on timing for that?

Comment: Lots of thoughts, but the most important is probably about 12 hours from now. :)

Comment: 12 hours, eh? I don't know what that means, but I suppose I'll find out tomorrow. The mystery!